# Retrieving a part of an HTML page with cURL in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a PHP script that gets the HTML from a website with curl. The probleem is i want to get only a specific part of the HTML for example:
The HTML code

```
<HTML>
<head></head>
<body>
  <div>
    <tabel>
      <TR>
        <td> text </td>
      </TR>
      <TR>
        <td> 
          <tabel>
            ....
          </tabel>
      </TR>
    </tabel>
  </div>
</body>
</HTML>
```

Now i want a string `text` and a string `....` 
But i can`t use id or class

Comment: and how you going to know which `text` is that `text` you want? best approach is to use DOM or xpath but if you can't use id or class then i suggest you try harder. or use regexp (lame but sometimes last resort)

Comment: [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php/3577662#3577662)

Comment: So what approach are you taking to do this? Where are you running into trouble?

Comment: **table** and not `tabel` ahem (You'll hit a brick wall with that code, *literally*)

Comment: Can`t i specifi a path or something like div/tabel/TR/td

Comment: This might be useful http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/get-between.htm

Comment: @RickC Did you bother to read the first answer there??

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski the test are always in the same place in the code the only diference is ons time the text is text land the ither time  Hello or something else

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse DOM. You can either use php [DOM extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php), or any library like [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) etc.

Comment: Then do i get all the divs or images cant it just be one

Comment: @Rick C: You get every single tag no matter what it is. (img, div, a, etc.)

Comment: But i only want the content within the td where text is nog all tds

Comment: The parsed data has a Tree structure. You can easily get any node you want. Just take a look at the given links! I don't know what problem you're facing!